# How to generate rank in Power BI on the basis of two column

Tags: powerbi, dax, ranking

I am new to Power BI and need some help regarding the Power BI `RANKX` function

So the scenario is I have `Emp name` and `emp_id` fields in my employee table and I have the `office_distance` and `emp id` column from the office table.

I want to create a column in my visual which contains ranking on the distance and name basis.

Example:

```
| EmpName | off_dist | Rank |
|-------- |----------|------|
|    A    |    10    |  1   |
|    A    |    20    |  2   |
|    A    |    30    |  3   |
|    B    |    20    |  3   |
|    B    |    10    |  1   |
|    B    |    15    |  2   |
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below DAX formulas for calculated columns. And if this post helps, then please consider Accept it as the solution to help the other members find it more quickly.

1. Create a column to rank by the Employee Name

   ```
   Rank EName = RANKX(ALL(Table), U381[Table], ,ASC, Dense)
   ```
2. Create another column to rank by Employee Name and by the Office Distance.

   ```
   Ranking on EName and Distance = 
   VAR X = MAX('Table'[Rank E_Name])

   var result = 
         RANKX(
            ALL(Table),
            Table[O_Distance] * X + Table[Rank E_Name], ,
            ASC
          )

   RETURN 
         result
   ```

[image: Output]